# Получить данные из API VK и записать их в БД

Tags: javascript, база-данных, vkontakte-api

Я пытаюсь сделать скриптик, который будет получать много данных из известного мне ИД пользователя ВК и записывать эти данные в БД. Как это сделать мало представляю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, хотя бы маленький примерчик, а я уже дальше расковыряю. Хотя бы на примере города пользователя или пола. Вот что-то похожее с фото и статусом, но без Базы данных.

```
$request = 'http://api.vkontakte.ru/method/users.get?uids=ID&fields=photo_200,status';
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$info = array_shift(json_decode($response)->response);

var_dump($info->photo_200); // URL фотографии
var_dump($info->status);    // Статус
```

Comment: Так вы же уже написали....правда на пхп.... Только вместо `ID` будет идентификатор пользователя

Comment: а `javasccript` тут зачем?

Comment: У вас смешаны мухи и котлеты. Задача делится на две совершенно независимые части: получить информацию из API ВКонтакте, и сохранить данные в базу. Спрашивайте о них по отдельности.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки

Answer (score 2):

На javascript из VK API получить записи со стены пользователя VK можно так:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function wall(id, callback, offset, count) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get",
        data: {
            owner_id: id,
            extended: 0,
            v: "5.44",
            offset: offset || 0,
            count: count || 100     // maximum
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: callback
    });
}
function toTable(data) {
    var tbl = $('#res');
    var td = function (v) { return $("<td>").text(v); }
    var tr = function (item, index) {
        $("<tr>")
            .append(td(index))
            .append(td(new Date(item.date * 1000).toLocaleString()))
            .append(td(item.id))
            .append(td(item.from_id))
            .append(td(item.owner_id))
            .append(td(item.text.substr(0, 20) + "..."))
            .appendTo(tbl);
    };
    data.response.items.forEach(tr);
}
$(function () { wall(1, toTable, 0, 5); });
</script>
```

---

```
<style>
#res { border-collapse: collapse; border-color: silver;}
    #res tr:first-child { font-weight: bold; }
</style>

<table id="res" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>index</td>
        <td>date</td>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>from_id</td>
        <td>owner_id</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]