# ajax не работает. jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

я новичок в этой теме, я взял код с одного из сайтов и хотел проверить как он работает, но в итоге он не работает, в чем проблема?

```js
function wall(id, callback, offset, count) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get",
    data: {
      owner_id: id,
      extended: 0,
      v: "5.103",
      offset: offset || 0,
      count: count || 100     // maximum
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: callback
  });
}

function toTable(data) {
  var tbl = $('#res');
  var td = function (v) { return $("<td>").text(v); }
  var tr = function (item, index) {
    $("<tr>")
        .append(td(index))
        .append(td(new Date(item.date * 1000).toLocaleString()))
        .append(td(item.id))
        .append(td(item.from_id))
        .append(td(item.owner_id))
        .append(td(item.text.substr(0, 20) + "..."))
        .appendTo(tbl);
  };
  data.response.items.forEach(tr);
}

$(function () { wall(1, toTable, 0, 5); });
```

```css
#res { border-collapse: collapse; border-color: silver;}
#res tr:first-child { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table id="res" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>index</td>
        <td>date</td>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>from_id</td>
        <td>owner_id</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

должно получится так
[image: должно получится так]

а получается вот так
[image: а получается вот так]

Comment: а с чего вдруг он должен работать?

Comment: если судить из этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488228/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-api-vk-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%94 то должен

Comment: вы возьмите прежде чем обрабатывать `data.response` проверьте, что в этой `data` находится. и увидите волшебную строку `User authorization failed: no access_token passed.`. Ответу на который вы ссылаетесь, уже 4 года как. Сверьтесь с документацией по методам и необходимости авторизации для их использования

Comment: teran, спасибо! Добавил access_token, изменил id на свою группу и всё заработало!